# Rails AJAX form keeps rendering as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ujs

i am attempting to add some ajax to a basic form, though it keeps rendering as html

Processing by OpponentsController#create as HTML

my view

```
<%= form_for(@opponent, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "opponents", :action => "create" }) do |f| %>
  <% if @opponent.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@opponent.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this opponent from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @opponent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
# POST /opponents
  # POST /opponents.json
  def create
    @opponent = Opponent.new(params[:opponent])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @opponent.save
        format.html { redirect_to(opponents_url,
                                  :notice => "#{@opponent.name}  was successfully created.") }
        format.js { render }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @opponent.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

create.js.erb

```
alert('Hello Rails');

enter code here
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the URL in your form_for, should be taken care of by calling form_for @opponent. Also check the form HTML and make sure it's actually setting data-remote="true"

Comment: looks like the data-remote is getting set ` <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/opponents" class="new_opponent" data-remote="true" id="new_opponent" method="post">`

Comment: And is the request coming into rails as JS or HTML? Are you sure you have JavaScript enabled on your browser?

Comment: how can i tell if its coming in as JS or HTML and yes javascript is enabled on my browser

Comment: In your console, it'll tell you the controller and action receiving the call, the method used (GET, PUT, POST, ..) and the format (JS, HTML)

Comment: Look at the logs, it will give details a out the incoming request, including what format the request is being processed with.

Comment: Started POST "/opponents" for 124.149.80.97 at 2013-02-03 15:29:08 +0100
Processing by OpponentsController#create as HTML

Comment: Fix this => format.js {render layout: false }

Comment: Well that's your problem. Is jquery loaded?

Comment: Does @opponent.name have validation? Does it work whether or not your give it a value?

Comment: jquery is loaded `= javascript_include_tag :rails, :jquery`

Comment: no validation, all it should be doing at the moment from my understand is calling the alert saying Hello Rails ?

Comment: You need jquery_ujs I think. Which version of Rails?

Comment: [root@ks354762 teammngt]# rails -v
ruby -vRails 3.2.8
[root@ks354762 teammngt]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]

Comment: @mathieugagne that seemed to be the issue missing the query lib :)

Comment: Good to hear, I'll put in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX forms require you to have jquery and jquery_ujs loaded. Make sure you include them in your application layout header or in your application.js file like so:

```
# application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```